# Why vertical-align using display:table doesn't work for me?

Tags: html, css

I want to align vertically text inside div, may have several lines.

Method from [CCS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)

HTML:

```html
   <div class="tutorial_step">
   <div style="display: table">
   <p>text<p/></div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.tutorial_step{
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-left:none;
    height: 350px;
     font-weight: bold;
    color:  #525252;
    background: #f9f9f9;}

.tutorial_step p{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nTR9/)

Comment: Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/3nTR9/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the `height` of the "table", otherwise the `height` will be the size of the `<p>`:

```
<div class="tutorial_step">
   <div style="display:table; height:100%;">
       <p>text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/3nTR9/3/

Comment: Also your closing P tag miss typed. it should be </p>.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you'd need to add those styles to the container.  The text in `p` is vertically aligned, but only within the `p` itself, which has no explicit height.

```css
    .tutorial_step {
        width: 400px;
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        border-left:none;
        height: 350px;
         font-weight: bold;
        color:  #525252;
        background: #f9f9f9;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

Works.